# Angular JS 2 -- Application Design

Tags: javascript, forms, angular

I got one main component for the FORM and have three component for sections

Now in the main form i have submit button which i want to use to submit all the section(s) data to a service?

How can i achieve this?

Do i use output event emitter in all the section components and get the data in the main form component before submitting?

Thank you

---------------------- initial question below ------------------------

I am creating a Form (with multiple sections) in angular2 and this form will be part of a approval workflow.

The workflow will be not in angular2, although the form will be referenced from the workflow. When we open the form from different stages of the workflow it will allow user to view or edit only certain sections of the form.

How should i design my form with sections?

1)  one component for the entire form?

2)  separate component for each sections and having one main parent component?

on the form load; run business logic check to find what section needs to be rendered in view and edit mode AND for business logic have a separate component which will check what section is loaded and in what mode

Please suggest an application design.

Answer (score 0):

The key thought here is re-usability and business logic.

Extract reusable components as their own component.

Lets say I have these components in my app ...

- Child Component A - some form inputs that i will reuse elsewhere
- Child Component B - Some form stuff that I will reuse

Parent Component A ...
Child Component A
And some stuff i wont reuse

Parent Component B ...
Child Component A
Child Component B
And some different stuff

Route Component, renders parent A or B depending on business logic as determined by incoming params / data.
Also, you might want to use attribute directives to add functionality to form elements. e.g. an attribute directive that transforms an input into a datepicker.

Comment: If I understand this correctly. Let's say My Form has sections A, B, C, .....    I can have separate components for each sections  i.e. component A, B, ...              now based on the params / data in the URL, I want to have my form displaying Section A in view mode and Section B in editable mode  so for this I can have a Main component which will call component A and B accordingly.   Now how the main component will call two templates? Please help

Comment: In other words One Component can have two or more child components but how does it display the templates from child components as per business logic meaning sometime just component A sometime both ...

Comment: at the most basic level you could use an *ngIf on the components in the parent